# C# Guardar imágenes dentro del ejecutable con código

Tags: c#

¿Puede guardar imágenes con Visual Studio dentro del ejecutable con código?
entiendo que se puede ser desde Visual Studio con su interfaz gráfica pero yo lo que intento es hacerlo con código

**¿Existe alguna forma de poder lograrlo?**

Comment: Realmente si puedes, no es que sea muy chulo ni muy elegante pero se me ocurre que podrias guardar cada imagen como una clave dentro del app.config por ejemplo

Comment: Al decir: "...desde Visual Studio con su interfaz gráfica...", ¿Estás indicando sobre los **Recursos (Resources)** de un proyecto de VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí lo que quieres hacer, hasta donde sé, la respuesta es simplemente no, ya que cuando ejecutas un ejecutable (válgame la redundancia) éste se ejecuta sólo en memoria y es volátil. Esto quiere decir que, una vez que cierres tu ejecutable, la memoria sera liberada y ¡PUMMM!, cualquier dato se borra.

Entonces lo que entiendo que quieres hacer es que tu ejecutable se re-escriba y se modifique para que guardes una imagen, lo cual hasta hoy no tengo conocimiento de que se pueda hacer.

Saludos.

Comment: Con ingeniera inversa quizás xd o cambiar los datos de la memoria o tal vez crear un compilador que cree el software modificado :) tu respuesta seria la correcta ya que los software de compilación hacen que esto sea difícil de realizar

Answer (score 0):

En Visual Studio una de las formas de guardar imágenes en el ensamblado es como recursos.

Estos recursos son definidos en el archivo del proyecto .csproj y lo que Visual Studio hace es mandar llamar la herramienta MSBuild y de parametro manda el archivo .csproj.

Asi se compila el código junto con los recursos declarados en el archivo .csproj.

Habiendo dicho esto podrías modificar el archivo .csproj para agregar las imagenes como recursos y asi tendrias a la hora de compilar las imagenes que necesitas.

Después con código puedes buscar estos recursos y usarlos como desees.